# Named entity disambiguation contests

Tags: nlp

I am interested in the field of **named entity disambiguation** and want to learn more about it. I have heard that there are contests organised by various associations on these kind of research topics. These contests are very helpful as they give a practical experience in these fields.

I found one such contest organised by Microsoft research [here](http://web-ngram.research.microsoft.com/erd2014/) though the dates have already passed. Can anyone point me to any other such contests ? Also, is there a site which catalogues these contests so that one can just go there and know about all upcoming contests ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check [this relevant answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/136760/31372) of mine on Cross Validated. I hope that it will be of your interest.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the GREC shared task challenges included a named entity recognition & coreference resolution component (i.e., disambiguation), but I don't think they've run GREC since 2010...?

https://sites.google.com/site/genchalrepository/reg-in-context/grec-ner